# Send mail from command line?

Tags: mail

How I can send a simple mail from Ubuntu command line without giving the password for the email account which I'm sending to?

Comment: If the question below worked, be sure to accept it by toggling the grey tick just beneath the answer's downvote button

Comment: "The password for the account you're sending ***to***"? No mail service asks the target account's password. O.o

Comment: @muru I think OP meant "without password for the email account I'm using"?

Comment: @DevRobot That's what I think too.  But I wonder if they used some command which asked for some password which they mistook for the target account's pw.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
mail -s "Subject" email@email.com
```

Press enter and write the subject of your email. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to continue.

You will be asked if you want to mark a copy of the mail to any other address - you can skip that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

The email will now be sent to your chosen address.

Comment: On 14.04, at least you must install the package `mailutils` first: The program 'mail' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: `sudo apt-get install mailutils`

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "Mail text" | mail -s "Subject" your@mail.com
```

Comment: How is this any better than [DevRobot's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/702709/158442)?

Comment: sending mail whithout text typing, can do some nice things like  df -h | mail -s "Disk Info" my@mail.com, redirect logs to your email sudo cat  /var/log/syslog | mail -s "logs" my@mail.com.  Just a suggestion...